# css the image is not changed although the code is changed

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012

I have this css

```
.header
{
    background-image: url('head-bcg.jpg');
    height: 62px;
}
```

I want to change the image so i did this

```
.header
{
    background-image: url('head-bcg-new.jpg');
    height: 62px;
}
```

but when i open the browser, i see the **old** image , please check what google chrome stats:
[image]

I tried:

1- clean the project

2- build and rebulid

3- restart the computer

but nothing works

Comment: Clear browser cache.. also check in different browser

Comment: @Hiral clearning cache is clearning history?

Comment: @Hiral i tried it now on firefox but i got empty picture why?

Comment: no.. press ctrl+shift+delete and tick: 
*) Clear browsing history  
*) Delete cookies and other site and plug-in data
*) Empty the cache

Comment: @Hiral i don't want to clear everything for just an image, i am using this computer and i care of the history, blugins..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the browser catch your codes. try CTRL+F5 for a few times or clear the browser's history

Comment: just a quesitn, when i closed the browser, the cache is removed automatically right?

Comment: I think when you close the browser, the browser doesn't remove catch but you can set the browser catch to "Never remember history" ... if you want